# htaccess limit rewrite rule to specific keywords

Tags: regex, .htaccess

Lets say i have a rule like this:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^-]+)-([^-]+)-([^.]+).htm$ /php_file.php?var1=$1&var2=$2&var3=$3&var4=$4&var5=$5&page=$6 [NC,L]
```

Is there a way to define a list of allowed keywords that can appear in 5th place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [regular expressions](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html#regex), you can define alternatives separated by a vertical bar `|`

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^-]+)-(key1|key2|key3)-([^.]+).htm$ /php_file.php?var1=$1&var2=$2&var3=$3&var4=$4&var5=$5&page=$6 [NC,L]
```